# Break down a data frame iteratively

Tags: r

I do have a question regarding iteratively create a matrix.

I am using the Mass package to generate random correlated data. Initially, I will generate a m X N matrix; where m is the number of column and N the number of rows. For instance, I will generate 20 X 10,000 matrix. I would like to be able to take the first two column and store them in a variable then take the first three column and store them in a matrix and so on. So, in the end I will have 19 new matrix.

Any help in this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the following suffices:

```
library(purrr)
M <- matrix(1,10000,20)
map(1:(ncol(M)-1), ~ M[,1:(.x+1)])
```